# split 関数の書き方が分からない

Tags: python

大変初歩的な質問だと思いますが、以下のサイトを参考に `split` 関数を試してみようとしていまして

[文字列を分割する！Pythonでsplit関数を使う方法を現役エンジニアが解説【初心者向け】](https://magazine.techacademy.jp/magazine/15553)

その際の `In[]` の中の書き方としては下記を二行で記載するようなイメージでよいのでしょうか？

```
result = 'オンライン、プログラミング、学習スクール、テックアカデミー'.split('、')
['オンライン', 'プログラミング', '学習スクール', 'テックアカデミー']
```

実行しても `Out[]` として下記が出てくるためおそらく間違っていると思うのですが、ちゃんとsplitされたものを表示するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

```
['オンライン', 'プログラミング', '学習スクール', 'テックアカデミー']
```

Comment: 「ちゃんとsplitされたものを表示するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？」とのことですが、「ちゃんとsplitされ」ています。文字列を区切り文字で区切った単語のリストとして返すのが”split()”です。関数の仕様を何か勘違いされているのでしょうね。https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Answer (score 1):

おそらく Jupyter Notebook 上で実行されているとして、参照されているサイトが言っているのは、

- In に `result = 'オンライン、プログラミング、学習スクール、テックアカデミー'.split('、')` を書いて実行すると、変数 `result` に `['オンライン', 'プログラミング', '学習スクール', 'テックアカデミー']` が代入される
- なのでたとえば後続の In に `print(result)` と書いて実行すると Out に `['オンライン', 'プログラミング', '学習スクール', 'テックアカデミー']` が出てくる

ということです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そういうことなんですか。確かに、print(result)で実行したところそのように表示されました。

Comment: これをさらに下記のように一つづつ表示するにはどうすればよいのでしょう？

オンライン

プログラミング

学習スクール

テックアカデミー